# How to force adding a custom attribute in the android namespace to a resource xml file of an android app

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, aapt

I tried to add a custom attribute in the android namespace to a view in a resource xml file in android app as follows:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:custom="" />
```

but got an error when building:

```
AAPT: error: attribute android:custom not found.
```

I just want to test how android system will behave when there is an unexpected attribute of android namespace in an app. Note that the custom attribute should be in android namespace. Is there a way to force adding such an attribute without triggering an error when building an apk. Or is there a way to achieve this by reverse engineering, e.g., unpacking, modifying and repacking an apk. Actually, I have also tried the reverse engineering way with apktool, but got the similar error as building an app, probably because apktool also leverages aapt to repack an apk. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a custom attribute to the android namespace.  That namespace is pre-defined and consists of only the built in Android attributes.  Adding a custom attribute adds it to the application namespace, by convention that's the app:XXX attributes (although that's a convention, you can call it anything you want).  Please note that custom attributes must be defined in attrs.xml, you can't just make one up in the layout xml.

Comment: You are right. However, my purpose is to build a malformed apk to test the robustness of android system. What I want to do is to bypass the xml schema restriction of aapt to craft an apk with unexpected attribute in the android namespace. Since aapt can identify this error, there must be a built-in xml schema or a standalone xml schema file that aapt can refer to. I have tried modified <sdk>\platforms\android-33\data\res\values\attrs.xml, which seems like a schema file for android resource, but it does not work. Could you help me to achieve such a goal?

Comment: In the layout file, you define the namespace where android maps to.  You can set that to anything you want.  Make a copy of it, edit the copy, point the layout file to that copy, and you should be good to go.  I'd expect it to not cause any issues at all unless you try to redefine an existing attribute-  this is all standard xml parsing stuff, nothing is likely to be special cased.

Comment: I can successfully build an apk using your method. However, this time the app fails to start, giving an error that a layout_width attribute is not supplied. I guess the reason is that aapt does not include the attribute into the apk when building resources, as the android namespace is not assigned a standard value. What should I do to fix this error?